# where does azure form recognizer store results?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

The Azure Cognitive Services Form Recognizer [API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v2-1/operations/AnalyzeWithCustomForm) accepts requests via a POST, and then makes the results available for 48 hours via a GET request to a resource:

```
POST "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/v2.1-preview.3/custom/models/{modelId}/analyze?includeTextDetails={boolean}

GET "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/formrecognizer/v2.1-preview.3/custom/models/{modelId}/analyzeResults/{resultId}]
```

Presumably Azure stores these results somewhere, but I can't find any documentation regarding it. After 48 hours, is the data deleted or just made unavailable? Where does the data reside? Who owns the data? Does the account owner have access to the underlying storage account or database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/fr-data-privacy-security) in their official doc. It mentions of a "The following diagram illustrates how your data is processed." but I cannot see one

Anyways, answering ahead....

> is the data deleted or just made unavailable?

deleted

The input data and results are deleted within 48 hours and not used
for any other purpose.
To learn more about privacy and security commitments, see the
[Microsoft Trust Center](https://www.microsoft.com/TrustCenter/CloudServices/Azure/default.aspx) and [cognitive services compliance and privacy](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/cognitive-services-compliance-and-privacy/).

> Where does the data reside? Who owns the data?

Azure internal

The incoming data is processed in the same region where the Cognitive
Services Azure resource was created. When you submit your documents to
a Form Recognizer operation, it starts the process of analyzing the
document to extract all text and identify structure and key values in
a document. Your data and results are then temporarily encrypted and
stored in Azure Storage.

When you create a Form Recognizer resource in the Azure portal, you
specify a region. From then on, your resource and all of its
operations stay associated with that particular Azure server region.

> Does the account owner have access to the underlying storage account or database?

Analyze Form Result API

The "Get Analyze Results" operation is authenticated against the same
API key that was used to call the "Analyze" operation to ensure no
other customer can access your data.

Azure temporarily stores the results for customers to retrieve: Analyze and
Get Results are asynchronous calls. In other words, the service
doesn't know when the customers will call the Get Results operation to
fetch the extracted results. To facilitate checking the completion
status and returning the extracted results to the customer upon
completion, the extracted results are stored temporarily in Azure
Storage. This behavior allows customers to poll the asynchronous Get
Results operation for job completion status and fetch the results upon
completion.

There is already a similar ask from a user in [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/932041-azure-cognitive-services/suggestions/43583202-cognitive-services-to-purge-it-completely-withou) forum, you can vote that too to get product group's attention ✌